# How to remove axes from XY Graph using jplot2d? Is there any way to make x axis and y axis invisible?

Tags: java, swing

I need the output of the program such a way that image produced should not have the axes. I tried many ways to make it invisible but I couldn't! So please help me out. The JAR I used was "JPLOT2D". I would even like to know how to remove axes using SWING too

Comment: How do you interpret a graph without axes?

Comment: I didn't mean to interpret a graph without Axes! What I wanted was to make the axes invisible. Anyway I got the ans by using the function setColor(Color.White); which is under the awt package.
Thanks.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).